# Is the landing location of a URI Fragment variable? Or is it always top?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, viewport, user-experience

So, when you with link internally on the page with eg. `<a href="#fragment">` to `<div id="fragment">`, and click it, it places the target always at the very top of the viewport(as far as the scrollbar will go that is.)

Is there a way to address/modify that location to, for example, the absolute center of your viewport?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a margin using the [`scroll-margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin) property. Add [`scroll-margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin) to the target element. (here `#fragment`).

**Example:**

```css
#fragment {
    margin: 1000px 0; /*Just to make the page scrollable*/
    scroll-margin: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<a href="#fragment">Click Me</a>

<div id="fragment">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur maxime, accusantium eius in iusto accusamus rerum dignissimos vero minima minus doloribus inventore ipsam distinctio, natus aut velit autem dolorem reprehenderit.
</div>
```

---

**Explanation:**

Here `scroll-margin: 50vh;`, `50vh` will make the element `#fragment` appear on 50% of the current viewport height when clicked on the link.

---

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/mdmrLbY?editors=1100)

Comment: Would this make the element centered or have the top of the element at the center?